# jQuery alerting index

Tags: jquery

i have a form made up of 6 steps - im trying to alert each index - at the moment the first index is being alerted but when i click next its alerting the first index and it breaks the script - it should be displaying the next index when i click on the next button. Why is this.get() not a function?

UPDATE: Its looping thorough the index's even when i click on the next button to go to step 2 of the form - do i need to do .click() function????

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.AspNet-DataList td a').each(function (index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
    ((this).get(text));
    $(this).css({ 'background-image': 'url(/assets/img/radarstep' + (index + 1) + 'faint.png)',
        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
        'height': '25px',
        'width': '25px',
    });
});
```

Comment: I fixed an error -> alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text() );

Comment: @Dezigo Javascript Error: Text is not defined

Comment: .get() expects an index. [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: delete this- > ((this).get(text));

Comment: @c-sharpnewbie It would help to know what you are trying to accomplish with `$(this).get(text);`

Comment: i have done @Dezigo - im trying to display the first index only without it breaking the script - and when i click the next button on the form im hoping for it to display the next index.

Comment: @AdityaManohar ive got rid of that line and its looping through the index's - im trying to like get it to alert on click now - so when a user clicks the next button to go to next part of the form it alerts the next index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the line `(this).get()`

The `this` object in this case an anchor tag `<a>` and there is no `.get()` method defined for the anchor tag.

Comment: right ive got the index to loop through all of them - im trying to loop it so when the user clicks the next button on the form it alerts the next index - do i need to do a .click function?

Comment: will give that a go - i'll have to edit my code and get it displaying somehow - i have a class called Asp.NET-Datalist